# Loading php file with AJAX in Wordpress frontend

Tags: ajax, wordpress

Trying out AJAX request for the first time and facing problem. I want to load a php file on button click in Wordpress site. So far after researching, I got this code:

1. index.php file:

   ```
   <button id="ajaxbtn">Ajax</button>
   <div id="ajax">Some Text</div>
   ```
2. ajax.php file (the file i want to be loaded):

   ```
   <?php echo "Hello!" ?>
   ```
3. functions.php file:

   ```
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myajax_data', 99 );
   function myajax_data(){

      wp_localize_script('menu_toggle', 'myajax', 
        array(
          'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
        )
      );  

   }

   add_action('wp_ajax_tablo', 'tablo');
   add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_tablo', 'tablo');

   function tablo() {

     // Grab php file output from server
     ob_start();
     include(get_template_directory_uri() . '/ajax.php');
     $result['content'] = ob_get_contents(); 
     $result = json_encode($result); // use wp_send_json instead to make this shorter
     echo $result;
     die();
   }
   ```
4. menu_toggle.js file (js file with ajax code):

   ```
   $("#ajaxbtn").click(function () {
     $.ajax({
       type : 'post',
       dataType : 'json',
       url : myajax.ajax_url,
       data : {action: 'tablo'},
       success: function(response) {
         //load the fetched php file into the div
         alert('Load was performed.');
         $('#ajax').append("hello"); 
         $('#ajax').load(response.content);
       }
     });
   });
   ```

I can actually get `alert('Load was performed.');` and `$('#ajax').append("hello");` displaying, so that means that ajax was connected right way and ajax request is working correctly. But `$('#ajax').load(response.content);` loading whole same index page in #ajax div instead of loading the content of ajax.php file i actually want. I probably got the wrong code either in `function tablo()` of functions.php file, or in ajax code of menu_toggle.js file. Can someone please help with this one?

Comment: Try to debug your `response` var in your `menu_toggle.js` file. You can `console.log(response)` and paste the content here.

Comment: the output of console log response is so big that i cant even copy it properly and paste it here cause this site won't allow so much characters in comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chetan Vaghela just helped with this problem on wordpress.stackexchange.com. If someone encounters with same problem as i had, please check Chetan Vaghela's answer below:

[Solution provided by Chetan Vaghela on wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/358077/loading-php-file-with-ajax-in-wordpress-frontend/358083#358083)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert/parse the json data in JS coming from PHP. Like :

```
var res = JSON.parse(response);
```

The full code look like :

```
$("#ajaxbtn").click(function () {
  $.ajax({
    type : 'post',
    dataType : 'json',
    url : myajax.ajax_url,
    data : {action: 'tablo'},
    success: function(response) {
      //load the fetched php file into the div
      var res = JSON.parse(response);

      alert('Load was performed.');
      $('#ajax').append("hello"); 
      $('#ajax').load(res.content);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm now getting error in console `Uncaught SyntaxError: 
 Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    
 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    
 at Object.success (menu_toggle.js:8)
    
 at c (jquery.min.js:2)
    
 at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    
 at l (jquery.min.js:2)
    
 at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)`

Comment: It actually causes due to non json format data is in response. Please console the response once before parsing it.

Comment: So adding `console.log(response);` before `var res = JSON.parse(response);` gives no result. Same error.

Comment: You need to check the Console Output whether any JSON format issues are there.

Comment: the console output gives crazy amout of lines I don't even know where i should look for issues